# Matlab: read and save multiple files

Tags: matlab, file, loops, for-loop

I want to read all wav files containing in a folder and save samples of each file in several cvs files containing in other folder.
This is my code:

```
     dirMask = 'inputFolder\*.wav';
    wavRoot = fileparts(dirMask);
    Files=dir(dirMask);

    for k=1:length(Files)
        FileNames = fullfile(wavRoot, Files(k).name);
        [s,fs] = audioread(FileNames);

    end

 fid = fopen('\filename.xls','a');
 fprintf(fid,'%f\n',num2str(s));
 fclose(fid);
```

This code doesn't work. How can I do this?

Comment: What do you mean "This code doesn't work"?

Comment: First of all you habe to specify a filenamemm rather than *.csv. Second: replace 'wt' with 'a' in order to append instead of overwriting your previous results again and again. Next it might be necessary to replace fprintf(...,s) with fprintf(...,num2str(s)), but not sure about that - maybe fprintf also converts it automatically.

Comment: I modified my code, but I want that samples of each wav file are visualized in each column of file xls\cvs. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, note that you are using %f which is for floats, but you are converting "s" into a string. Also, \n jumps to the next line, so if you need several columns you will have to check when to use \n or \t (tab) or just ";" for example. Check [matlab data formatting](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html) in any case

So if you know the exact number of columns (e.g. 3 columns) you can write:

```
fprintf(fid,'%s \t %s \t %s \n',string1, string2, string3);
```

If you want to do it within a loop you can check your iterator and add "\n" every X strings.

E.g.

```
ncols = 3
for i = 1:21
    mystring = num2str(i)
    if mod(i,ncols) == 0
       fprintf(fid,'%s \n',mystring); 
    else
       fprintf(fid,'%s ', mystring); 
    end
end
```